# Byte corruption with fwrite on large files

Tags: c++, http

Im developing a c++ program (most like an exercise class) about a client and a server, using HTTP protocol, the user give to the client a file file name and size (bytes), then the client create n threads and each one ask for an specific number of bytes to the server, the server attend the order and the client receive the data and put all together.

My program work fine for small files (100kb - 200kb), but when I try to send large files (Mb for example) from the server all bytes are received but the final file is corrupted, every thread had its own init and end byte number and create a file named like "file_n.txt" so there isn't problem in the order of the bytes at the time of put all the bytes together, the final corrupted file have the same number of bytes than the original (all bytes were received, also I check the server logs about the bytes interval the thread is asking for) but it's hexdump is different (obviously).

Did you think fwrite function has something to do with this issue? if yes, will be cool you point me to the right direction please, Im trying hard to solve this problem, this is my client.cpp code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_HEADER_SIZE = 1000;
int threadsEnd = 0;

struct bytes
{
  int initByte;
    int endByte;
  int bufferSize;
  int id;
  char * port;
  char * ip;
  char * image;
};

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

void * request_bytes (void * parameters)
{
  struct bytes * p = (struct bytes *) parameters;

  int sockfd, portno, n;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;

  int totalBuffer = MAX_HEADER_SIZE + p->bufferSize + 1;
  int totalBodyContent = p->bufferSize + 1;

  char buffer[totalBuffer];
  char bodyContent[totalBodyContent];

  portno = atoi(p->port);
  server = gethostbyname(p->ip);

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");


  ostringstream init,end;
  init << p->initByte;
  end << p->endByte;

  string HttpRequestString = string("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n") 
                           + string("Host: ") + p->ip + string("\n")
                           + string("Connection: Close\n")
                           + string("Content-Length: 4\n")
                           + string("Content-Type: txt\n\n")
                           + string("nombre=") + p->image + string("&inicio=") + init.str() + string("&fin=") + end.str() + string("\n");

  const char * HttpRequest = HttpRequestString.c_str(); 

  n = write(sockfd,(void *)HttpRequest, strlen(HttpRequest));

  if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR writing to socket");

  bzero(buffer,(MAX_HEADER_SIZE + p->bufferSize));
  int headerEndDetermined = 0, bodyEnd = 0;

  int x = 1;
  int bodyInit = 1;
  int total_bytes = 0;

  n = read(sockfd,buffer,((MAX_HEADER_SIZE + p->bufferSize) - 1));

  if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR reading from socket");

  for(; x < strlen(buffer); x++)
    if(buffer[x - 1] == '\n')
      if(buffer[x] == '\n')
      {
         headerEndDetermined = 1;
         bodyInit = x + 1;
         break;
      }


  for(x = 0; x < p->bufferSize ; x++)
  {
    bodyContent[x] = buffer[bodyInit];
    bodyInit++;
  }

  //Escritura de archivo
  char filename[32];
  snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * 32, "file%i", p->id);

  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen (filename,"wb");
  if(pFile != NULL)
  {
    fwrite (bodyContent,1,sizeof(bodyContent) - 1,pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
  }

  close(sockfd);
  threadsEnd++;

  return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 5) {
       fprintf(stderr,"uso %s hostname puerto image_name bytes\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
  }

  int globalByte = atoi(argv[4]);
  int threadRequest = 10;
  int requestBytes = (globalByte / threadRequest);
  int globalInitialByte = 1;
  int globalEndByte = requestBytes;
  int x = 0, i = 1;
  int totalBytesRequested = 0;

  pthread_t request[threadRequest];

  for(; x < threadRequest; x++){
    struct bytes request_args;

    request_args.initByte = globalInitialByte;
    request_args.endByte = globalEndByte;
    request_args.bufferSize = requestBytes;
    request_args.id = x + 1;

    globalInitialByte = globalEndByte + 1;
    globalEndByte = globalEndByte + requestBytes;

    if(x == (threadRequest - 1))
    {
      if((totalBytesRequested + requestBytes) < globalByte)
      {
        request_args.endByte = globalByte; 
        request_args.bufferSize = requestBytes + (globalByte - (totalBytesRequested + requestBytes));
      }    
    }
    request_args.ip = argv[1];
    request_args.port = argv[2];
    request_args.image = argv[3];

    pthread_create (&request[x], NULL, &request_bytes, &request_args);
    pthread_join (request[x], NULL); 

    totalBytesRequested += requestBytes;
  }

  /*do
  {
    cout<<"Threads completos: "<<threadsEnd<<endl;
  }while(threadsEnd < threadRequest);*/

  string createFileString = string("cat ");
  for(; i <= threadRequest; i++)
  {
    ostringstream filen;
    filen << i;
    createFileString = createFileString + string("file") + filen.str() + string(" ");
  }
  createFileString = createFileString + string("> new_") + argv[3];                  
  system(createFileString.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry about my bad grammar :p.

Comment: Do the N single files written by the N threads contain the correct data?

Comment: if the original file is 1000 bytes, and i create 10 threads every "file_n.txt" have 100 bytes so the size is good, im not sure about the content (it works for small files), but let me check with hexdump (individual file) again and I'll tell you.

Comment: Yes, go and check those N files, as this is essentially to sort out whether the malfunction's root cause lies in the server-side file-chopper, the sender, the receiver or the client-side file-merger.

Comment: Forgive me if I harbor suspicions of your buffer size usage calculations. Specifically, tail byte of each frame. These are raw bytes, so i'm not entirely sure you need to +1 your buffer size, nor -1 it (which is done in one specific place I think is questionable.) I would start with those. The problem would be exacerbated if the under-byte happens to agree with whatever value was in the buffer, thereby masking the problem. Short version: recheck your buffersize logic and how it is filled, then written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of bugs.

1. The HTTP protocol specifies that lines must end with "\r\n", not "\n".
2. You specify a content length of four bytes, but your content is longer than that.
3. Don't use `sizeof` or `strlen` when your code already knows the sizes of things. It will get you into trouble.
4. You only call `read` once. You need to keep calling `read` until you receive all the data.
5. You specify HTTP 1.1 compliance, but your code doesn't actually comply with the HTTP 1.1 specification. For example, your code would break horribly if you received data with chunked encoding. HTTP 1.1 clients are *required* to support chunked encoding. "*All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the `chunked` transfer-coding*[.]" -- [RFC2616 3.6.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I'll read more about HTTP ( I didnt know about the \r thanks for that), the content-lenght: 4 was only and example right now the server just parse the body of the request, I want to ask about the keep reading stuff, rigth now (calling only one time the method) every file_n.txt is filled with n bytes, did you mean  I could have 100 bytes of trash at the end :s?

Comment: @Alevsk: You could read just one byte. The `read` function on a TCP socket gives you whatever data is available, blocking if needed until at least one byte is available. You need to keep calling `read` until you read all the data. You need to actually implement the HTTP protocol to determine when you have all the data. (I'd suggest implementing HTTP 1.0 as that makes it pretty easy -- you have all the data when `read` returns zero.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can declare character string sizes at run time, you will need to change

```
char buffer[totalBuffer];
char bodyContent[totalBodyContent];
```

to

```
char buffer = new char[totalBuffer];
char bodyContent = new char[totalBodyContent];
```

and delete the buffers at the end

```
delete [] buffer;
delete [] bodyContent;
```

Alternatively, you could use `malloc()` and `free()` to allocate and free the buffers.